# Argmin is zero how fixed it

Tags: python, numpy, synchronization

I got code for coupled system and i need to see synchronization, but argmin is 0. How i can fixed it? For another c0 his working good, but result not what i want, when i use 0.2+, his break because np.argmin=0, i dont know what to do...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
с0 = 0.00313
c1 = 2.78
c11 = 2.89
c3 = 3
m0 = 1
m1 = 2
m=m0/m1
def f(x1):
    f = ((-m)*x1)+(1/2)*((m0+m1)/m1)*(abs(x1+1.0)-abs(x1-1.0))
    return f
def dH_dt(H, t=0):
        return np.array([(-c1/c3)*(f(H[1]-H[0])),
                     (-1/c3)*(f(H[1]-H[0])+H[2]),
                     c3*H[1],
                     (-c11/c3)*(f(H[4]-H[3])),
                     (-1/c3)*(f(H[4]-H[3])+H[5])+(с0/c3)*(H[1]-H[4]),
                     c3*H[4]])
t = np.arange(0,1000, 0.01)
H0 = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002]
H, infodict = integrate.odeint(dH_dt, H0, t, full_output=True)
x1=H[10000:,0]
x2=H[10000:,3]
def simFn(x1,x2, skew):
    if skew == 0:
        diff_skew = x1 - x2
    else:
        diff_skew = x1[skew:] - x2[:-skew]
    diff_skew_avg = np.average(diff_skew*diff_skew)
    x1_sq_avg = np.average(x1*x1)
    x2_sq_avg = np.average(x2*x2)
    factor = np.sqrt(x1_sq_avg*x2_sq_avg)
    return diff_skew_avg/factor
dt = 0.01
tau = np.arange(0,30,dt)
S = np.array([ simFn(x2,x1,int(_tau/dt)) for _tau in tau ])
minskew = np.argmin(S[:1000])
print(minskew)
plt.plot(x1[:-minskew], x2[minskew:])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel('$x1(t + \Delta t)$')
ax.set_ylabel('$x2(t)$')
plt.show()
```

error is:

```
minskew=0
```

Need to see oblique line as result

[http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/~pikovsky/pdffiles/1997/prl_78_4193.pdf](http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/%7Epikovsky/pdffiles/1997/prl_78_4193.pdf)

[simFN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKG4C.png)
[expected this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khpgo.png)

Comment: Sorry, this code that you posted is working fine (it is reaching the end without exceptions).  I tried changing c0 to  0.2, 0.21, etc but still working.

Comment: until 0.28 it works but then stops @AmoRobb

Comment: The code itself looks fine. Your algorithm is finding the `minskew` as the zero position in `S` and `x1[:-minskew]`will crash because it is expecting `minskew` greater than zero. So the problem is your algorithm or your assuptions. If it is mathematically impossible that `minskew` equals zero, then review the algorithm. If you tell us what it is expected for `x1` and `x2`, and what `simFn` is expected to calculate in detail, maybe we can help with the algorithm

Comment: @AmoRobb i add simFn and what i expected

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the solution is in your code already. From the article attached:

> If x1(t) = ­ x2(t), as in the case of CS, S(tau) reaches its minimum sigma =­ 0 for tau =­ 0

So, without getting deeper in your algorithm, I would say that `minskew == 0` means that both signals are almost completely coupled. The only thing missing is that precise condition that you did use in your `simFn` method, regarding the case of `tau==0`. Thus, I would simple rewrite your plotting to:

```py
   #[...]
   minskew = np.argmin(S[:1000])
   print(minskew)
   if minskew == 0:
       plt.plot(x1, x2)
   else:
       plt.plot(x1[:-minskew], x2[minskew:])
 
   #[...]
```

In my case, I don't see a perfect straight line for `c0=0.28` (although quite correlated), but I don't know if it is due to your samples generator, numeric precision or some issue in your algorithms, of if it is actually what you expect.

Comment: yes, its working, but system is dynamical, i need chaotic(

Comment: what do you mean?